# What is the Future of Apache Hbase

Tags: hadoop, hbase, cloudera, hortonworks-data-platform, nosql

Well i wanted to know What is the Future of Hbase. As we know that it is used in case of Real-Time scenario But so is Cassandra & MongoDB. The only advantage HBase gets is that it comes along packaged with Cloudera / HDP distribution.

So how useful or effective is to get Deep into Hbase. .???

Answer (score 0):

Per CAP (Consistency, Availability and Partition Tolerance) theorem the NoSQL databases can have only 2 of the 3 requirements.  Depending that use case following 2 groups are formed.

HBASE and MongoDB are CP system (Consistency and partition tolerance)
Cassandra has AP (Availability and partition tolerance).

HBASE and Cassandra are column oriented However, MongoDB is document type.
HBASE architect is master-worker and Cassandra is master-less. Cassandra offers robust support for cluster spanning multiple datacenters.
Functional key difference is HBASE still has low latency read and write compared with Cassandra for high throughput.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HBase

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Cassandra